# how to get function's return type whose formal parameter is reference of abstract class

Tags: c++, type-traits

I want to know `fun`'s return type, but I neither can construct an object of A nor have a function like `int fun(A&& a)`, What should I do？

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

struct A {              // abstract class
  virtual int value() = 0;
};

int fun(A& a) {
    return 0;
}


int main() {
    decltype(fun(std::declval<A>())) retValue; //wrong

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you mean in case were fun would be templated? I don't really understand what you mean by return type as its clearly an int in this case

Comment: @MichałTurek in case fun is called in a templated function, like fun(std::declval<T>()), but fun is overloaded for different parameter's types. sorry not described clearly

Comment: I still don't get it why are you doing this, can you enclose a more specific case that this is necessary? As far as I can see `decltype(fun(std::declval<A&>())) retValue;` is just fine.

Comment: you've already answered my question. I didn't know `declval` can be used like this `std::declval<A&>()`, thank you so much.